# Разделение изображений из одной директории на сеты

Tags: python, изображения, split, dataset

Всем доброго времени суток. Подскажите, как разделить на Train, Validation и Test сеты набор картинок из одной директории?

Пробовал sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split. Но так получиться только Train и Test.
Смотрел примеры из tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator, но там получается наоборот Train и Validation.
Как сразу создать три множества картинок?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38251213/5741205

Comment: Да, но там разбитие dataframe. На каталоге с изображениями это не сработает.